# Unable to get the desired result or output while using if-else statement inside a For loop of a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am stuck at below batch script for couple of days. Am not able to get my expected output. My if-else statement is not working as I expect. I want it to do certain actions when it encounters "----" and move to else statement otherwise. My output is always executing one else statement every single time.

```
else (
ECHO(!arga!,"","",!argd!,!arge!,!argf!,!argg!,!argh!)>>myFile.csv
)
```

Either the value of variable is not getting updated or there is some issue with my logic.

I am a beginner to batch scripting, I wrote the if-else statements based on C/Java/Python programming knowledge. I am confused whether I should go for GOTO labels to perform my desired function.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

del "C:\Program Files\report.txt"
del myFile.csv
del test1.csv
call "C:\Program Files\report.bat" >> "C:\Program Files\report.txt"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "skip=3 usebackqtokens=1-7*delims= " %%a in (report.txt) do (
set "arga=%%a"
set "argb=%%b"
set "argc=%%c"
set "argd=%%d"
set "arge=%%e"
set "argf=%%f"
set "argg=%%g"
set "argh=%%h"
    if !argb! equ [-----] (
        if !argd! equ [-----] (
        ECHO(!arga!,"","","","",!argf!,!argg!,!argh!)>>myFile.csv
        ) else (
        ECHO(!arga!,"","",!argd!,!arge!,!argf!,!argg!,!argh!)>>myFile.csv
        )
    ) else (
        if !argd! equ [-----] (
        ECHO(!arga!,!argb!,!argc!,"","",!argf!,!argg!,!argh!)>>myFile.csv
        ) else (
        ECHO(!arga!,!argb!,!argc!,!argd!,!arge!,!argf!,!argg!,!argh!)>>myFile.csv
        )
    )
)

del newMyFile.CSV
echo jobName,lastStartdate,lastStartTime,lastEndDate,lastEndTime,status,runPri,exit > newMyFile.CSV

type myFile.csv >> newMyFile.CSV

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=," %%a in ("newMyFile.CSV") do (
      ECHO %%a
)
```

Comment: The `)` you intend to write to the file - it prematurely closes your `if` or `else` clauses. Escape it `echo (foobar^)`

Comment: I would just rewrite your `echo` commands like this: `>>myFile.csv ECHO !arga!,"","",!argd!,!arge!,!argf!,!argg!,!argh!`

Comment: You don't need the closing `)` for `echo` statements at all, and in fact it adds an extra one to your output since the `(` is parsed separately and doesn't get displayed.

Comment: @Stephan @Squashman @SomethingDark Thank you so much, the `)` was the issue. Its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as all of the advice already provided in the comments, you don't need to set any variables, or use delayed expansion. Additionally you don't need to pre-delete any files if you use the redirection operator `>`, and you also should not need to create `report.txt`, or `myFile.csv` either. Finally, you don't need a `for /f` loop to view your new file, you can just use `type`. I'd expect that the following batch file example would perform the same task, much more simply, *and quicker too!*

This rewrite assumes that you don't really intend to create your CSV file in `Program Files`, which would require your script to be 'Run as administrator', but in the current directory instead.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

(   Echo jobName,lastStartdate,lastStartTime,lastEndDate,lastEndTime,status,runPri,exit
    For /F "Skip=3 Tokens=1-7,*" %%G In ('"C:\Program Files\report.bat"'
    ) Do If "%%H" == "[-----]" (If "%%J" == "[-----]" (
            Echo %%G,"","","","",%%L,%%M,%%N
        ) Else Echo %%G,"","",%%J,%%K,%%L,%%M,%%N) Else If "%%I" == "[-----]" (
        Echo %%G,%%H,%%I,"","",%%L,%%M,%%N
    ) Else Echo %%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L,%%M,%%N
) 1> "newMyFile.CSV"

Type "newMyFile.CSV"
Pause
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and suggestions. Your improved version worked like a charm. Thank you.